# Google Play Game Services - AchievementBuffer in wrong order

Tags: android, achievements, google-play-games

I'm finishing a game featuring Google Play Game Services, but i still have one main issue to solve.

I got several Achievements available for my game, but when i load and display them, they seem to be in the wrong order :/

Instead of having [Achievement 1, Achievement 2, Achievement 3, Achievement 4, Achievement 5, Achievement 6, Achievement 7], i have [Achievement 3, Achievement 2, Achievement 1, Achievement 4, Achievement 5, Achievement 6, Achievement 7].

Can anyone help me with this issue ? Leaderboards are correct...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achievements are displayed sorted by the time you achieved it!

On your example, first your got #1, then #2 and then #3. Achievements #4, #5, #6 and #7 weren't achieved yet, right?

Comment: Thanks, it's the case. There should be an "order" param, it would be more convenient ^^

Comment: Fully agree about the "order" param